# DataGridView connection with database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datagridview

I am very often in a need for connecting DataGridView with database. I always have struggles what to use - should I use manually typed code by myself or should I use some kind of built in mechanism like datasets for insert/update/delete/select.

With built in code the problems I have encountered were that in case of exceptions I don't know how to catch them in automatically generated code? There is a lot of code generated behind the scenes when I use built in mechanism for connection with database and I don't thinks it's smart to merge my code with generated code.

If I type code manually, I have full control of everything - but, I have to do it for each particular DataGridView.

I always use the same principle: for insert/update/delete/select I am using stored procedures inside sql server database. I never use sql queries inside my application. I just don't like them, I think that code gets too messy with them and there is also a possibility of sql injection.

I was succesfully using manually typed code - but each time I have to build some app I ask myself if there is another way of doin' it? Perhaps shorter way or something that can be re-used in another application?

Comment: Make a DataGridView library with an ability to add custom columns

Comment: You mean create my own custom class which inherits from DataGridView? Custom user control?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can derived your own class from DataGridView, lets say DerivedDataGridView

I did a similar kind of project some time back and I always use that control for populating the dataGridView

```
public DataTable AddGridRow<T>(IEnumerable<T> rowData, params String[] columnNames)
{
  HashSet<String> columnsHashSet = new HashSet<String>(columnNames);

  PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

  foreach (T item in rowData)
  {
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
    {
       DataRow newRow = _dataGridTable.NewRow();
       foreach (DataColumn column in _dataGridTable.Columns)
       {
           if (columnsHashSet.Contains(prop.Name))
           {
             newRow[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
             break;
           }
        }
    }
  _dataGridTable.Rows.Add(newRow); // _dataGridTable is existing DataTable
}
```

This is the function which creates your custom DataTable and then you can assign it as the datasource. Your data could be anything derived from IEnumerable & You just have to give column Names

Now when populating from Datatable, Just assign your newly created Datatable as datasource

```
var newTable = _dataGridTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, columnNames); //columnNames is string[]
DerivedDataGridView.DataSource = newTable;
```